# How to make one page link to another page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am requiring help in Wordpress page link. I am displaying the page title using

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&include=49&title_li'); ?>
```

This page has `POST ID = 49`. How could I make this page should link to `POST = 51`.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 49 to 51.

If you mean you want to create a link to post 51 using the title of post 49, then use [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) to get the title of post 49, and [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) to get the permalink for post 51.

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(51) . '">' . get_the_title(49) . '</a>';
```